# Php decoding function in PHP

Tags: php, decode, encode

This is a function that I use in my Jquery code.

```
function atou(str) {
        return decodeURIComponent(escape(window.atob(str)));
}
```

Can someone write here a similar PHP function with the same functionality?
Thanks

Comment: Do you understand what each of the functions there does?

Comment: We don't translate code here. If you've tried something please add that and explain what doesnt work. If you use the PHP manual you can probably find each equivalent function though..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack isn't a free conversion service.

Comment: I'll try to answer to the 3 gentlemen that responded: 1. I don't really understand what the functions do but I the bottom line is decoding in javascript and it works. I use also the encoding function and both work fine in JS: function utoa(str) {
  return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(str)));
   }   2.Its not a translation-its actually a need of a similar functionality in PHP

Answer (score 0):

```
function atou($str) {
    return urldecode(urlencode(base64_decode($str)));
}
```

Comment: I'll try it and comment later

Comment: I checked BareNakedCoder answer. It works fine in general. Problem is that I use Hebrew in the encoded string and this decoding function doesn't know to decode it. Can you or anybody else improve it?